# Просто открыть файл формата .xlsx

Tags: php, phpexcel

Нужно просто открыть указанный файл формата .xlsx Дальше он будет правиться и закрываться вручную. Подключил внешние модули PHPExcel :

```
...\Classes\PHPExcel.php    и    ...\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php
```

Далее так :

```
$pExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("C:\\info\\p_f600.xlsx");
```

Работать с листом и т.д. получается, например, так :

```
   // выбираем лист, с которым будем работать;
   $pExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
   // получаем активный лист;
   $aSheet = $pExcel->getActiveSheet();
```

Но мне нужно просто открыть файл. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "просто открыть"? Просто открыть в Microsoft Word? Просто скачать и открыть? Просто открыть как набор байт? Что?

Comment: файл .xlsx уже существует на компе, нужно его открыть для внесения / коррекции содержимого и потом закрытия вручную, - в теле вопроса так и написано ...

Comment: Вам может и понятно, но, к сожалению, все телепаты ушли в отпуск. Вот тут `$pExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("C:\\info\\p_f600.xlsx");`  вы "просто открываете", но это видимо не оно. Потом у вас откуда то берется "закрыть руками" - ШТА!? По русски объясните, чего именно вы хотите добиться. Вот прям по шагам, например - "хочу тыркнуть по файлу, чтоб запустился редактор и в нем открылся этот файл, потом руками его поправить и сохранить"

Comment: @rjhdby кажется автор хочет запустить Excel с этим файлом.

Comment: @rjhdby , спасибо за помощь, да, именно, как Вы и описали, - чтобы запустился редактор Excel с этим файлом. "потом руками его поправить и сохранить"

Comment: @Alex PHPExcel вам с этим не поможет. да и пхп тоже плохо подходит для этих целей. Каков смысл задачи то вообще?

Comment: @teran , Вы не в курсе, - на java так можно ? Нужно из разных мест html файла (из браузера Chrome) открывать разные, но уже существующие файлы .xlsx Пока делаю вручную, - хотел поправить, - для личного пользования ...

Comment: @Alex  у вас на локальной машине сайт? и надо открывать тут же? Если так то попробуйте [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php) в качестве аргумента должен быть полный путь к `Excel.exe` и параметром имя файла. То есть такая команда, которая делает то что надо через Пуск-Выполнить. Не уверен, правда, что запустится. Т.к. apache/iis работают от имени другоо пользователя.

Comment: @teran , сейчас попробую ...

Comment: Если PHP крутится на Windows, то расширение COM вам в помощь. http://php.net/manual/ru/book.com.php

Comment: да, на Windows, спасибо, - попробую

Comment: @alex просто `exec("D:\\test.xlsx")` не надо дергать сам эксель.

Comment: @teran , Ваш пример у меня работает. Большое спасибо. Правда, открывает не поверх окон, но уже гораздо веселее. Thanks

Comment: @Alex чтобы поверх окон было напрямую из пхп не получится. Придется писать какую-нибудь программу или скрипт, которая на вход будет получать имя файла, создавать процесс, а потом его уже двигать вперед.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для выполнения внешней команды на сервере (или в данном случае на локальной машине, где размещен сервер) используйте функцию [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php)

```
exec("C:\\info\\p_f600.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 1):

Для PHP работающем на платформе Windows доступно расширение, позволяющее оперировать [COM объектами](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.com.php)

Там же в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.com.php) есть пример запуска Microsoft Word. Вам по, аналогии надо, будет создать объект для Excel.

```
<?php
$ex = new COM("Excel.sheet") or Die ("Did not connect");
$ex->Application->Workbooks->Open("C:\\info\\p_f600.xlsx");

//Если автоматом не будет на передний план выходить, то
$ex->Application->Visible = 1;
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51294/discussion-on-answer-by-rjhdby-----xlsx).